# Like button - Admin page and OG tag don't agree

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

when I first rolled out the Like button for our site I inadvertently left the test site url in the OG url tag.  I liked the site and then went to the admin page where I discovered my error.

I fixed the og tag and rolled out a new version of the page.  The OG tag is now correct, and the FB linter comes up clean.  However, if I go the admin page it still shows the test site url.  If I go to a different browser and like the page the admin page is correct.

How can get the first browser to go to the correct admin page?

Worse, we seem to be getting likes on both the test site and the live site. We're a small organization so both sites are sub directories of the same domain, although the full path to the root is given in the og url tag:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://birdweb.org/birdweb/" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching issue - just clean your cache in the problematic browser and all should be fine.